# Taller than normal parallel symbol ||

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'd love to achieve a nice format for the following snippet:

`$$Z_{eq}(j\omega) = R_0 + \left(R_1 + \frac{1}{j\omega C_1}\right) || \left(R_2 + \frac{1}{j\omega C_2}\right)$$`

If printed as such, the `||` bars aren't tall enough to get a nice result.

I've also tried this solution but it doesn't work either.

`$$Z_{eq}(j\omega) = R_0 + \left(R_1 + \frac{1}{j\omega C_1}\right)\parallel \left(R_2 + \frac{1}{j\omega C_2}\right)$$`

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle has already noted in a comment, you may want to replace `\parallel` with `\Vert`. Importantly, the symbol produced by `\Vert` can be enlarged vertically with the help of the `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg` prefixes: `\big\Vert`, `\Big\Vert`, `\bigg\Vert`, and `\Bigg\Vert`. Finally, in case you need a bit of extra spacing around the double vertical lines, you could use the additional prefix element `m`: `\bigm\Vert`, `\Bigm\Vert`, `\biggm\Vert`, and `\Biggm\Vert`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' environment
\begin{document}
\[ 
\begin{split}
Z_{\mathrm{eq}}(j\omega) 
&= R_0 + \biggl(R_1 + \frac{1}{j\omega C_1}\biggr) 
   \bigg\Vert \biggl(R_2 + \frac{1}{j\omega C_2}\biggr)\\[1ex]
&= R_0 + \biggl(R_1 + \frac{1}{j\omega C_1}\biggr) 
   \biggm\Vert \biggl(R_2 + \frac{1}{j\omega C_2}\biggr)
\end{split} 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe this is a case for `equation` and `split` rather than `align`.

Comment: @egreg - Good idea. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a macro that seems to work well:

```
\newcommand{\scaleparallel}[2]{
    \left. {#1} \middle| \kern-0.1em \middle| {#2} \right.
}
```

Example that also uses the \align and \frac macros from the amsmath package:

```
Let
\begin{align}
  Z_1 &= \scaleparallel{\frac{1}{sC}}{R} \\
  Z_2 &= \scaleparallel
        {
          \frac
            {
              \scaleparallel
                {R_1 + \scaleparallel{R_2}{R_3}}
                {\left( R_2 + R_3 \right)}
            }
            {2} 
        }
        {R_4}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Here is an in-line example: `\(\scaleparallel{\frac{1}{sC}}{\left( -\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \right)}\)`

[image]